# How to use AS in SQL INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I am new in Mysql. I have multiple tables and i want to join all of them. I use INNER JOIN for this.

```
"SELECT *
FROM table
               INNER JOIN table2
               ON table.client_id = table2.id

           WHERE table2.id= 113
           ORDER BY table.id DESC
           LIMIT 1 ";
```

Here i face a problem that i have a column name title in each table. I want to use AS in my command. Like in outlook table there is name of column is TITLE i want to use it as outlook_title. How it is possible?

I want to use echo to print data like this

```
echo '<h1>' .$row["client"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["name"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["name"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["ation_title"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["look_title"]. '</h1>' ;
```

Please help me

Comment: Use `og_outlooks.title` in the select,just preface the column with the table name.

Comment: col name titles can be slightly different to clue you in too

Comment: @Mihai please refer me syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said every table, what do I know:>

Add other columns at your leisure.

```
SELECT r.title as rtitle,c.title as ctitle,
t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle
FROM og_ratings r 
INNER JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
INNER JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
INNER JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
INNER JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
WHERE c.id= 113
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give alias using AS to your columns and also to a `subquery` result

```
SELECT s.title as stitle,p.title as ptitle
FROM og_ratings s 
INNER JOIN og_companies p
ON s.client_id = p.id
WHERE s.id= 115
```